# Selenium 3.12 shows an error on driver.quit() @ FireFox 60 / Win 7 Home Premium / Java 10.0.1 / GeckoDriver 0.20.1

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My PC:

Win 7 / 64 Bit - all updates installed
FireFox 60.0 / 64 Bit
Java 10.0.1
Selenium 3.12
Geckodriver 0.20.1 / 64 Bit
Eclipse 4.7.3a

JAVA-Sourcecode:

```
public class SeleniumFireFoxMinimal1 {                                                             
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {                           
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "e:\\geckodriverwrapper.bat");                       
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                 
        driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");                                                      
        driver.quit();                                                                             
    }                                                                                              
}
```

geckodriverwrapper.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF  
ECHO Starting geckodriver: %0 %*  
E:\geckodriver.exe --log trace %* > NUL 2>&1
```

Eclipse console output:

```
Starting geckodriver: E:\geckodriverwrapper.bat --port=27751 -b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
Mai 12, 2018 1:14:15 VORM. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMATION: Detected dialect: W3C
```

The following lines are shown 15s after the Firefox window is closed:

```
Mai 12, 2018 1:14:37 VORM. org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFORMATION: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stopThread(PumpStreamHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:443)
    at at.xxxxxxx.work.SeleniumFireFoxMinimal1.main(SeleniumFireFoxMinimal1.java:40)
Mai 12, 2018 1:14:37 VORM. org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to kill process Process[pid=4320, exitValue=1]
```

Other Selenium commands like these work perfectly well:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("sinp"));              
element.clear();                                                
element.sendKeys("black");                                      
element.submit();
```

Is this just a problem on my PC ?

`driver.quit()` is working on InternetExplorer without a problem.

Maybe we have to reopen this issue?:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4678

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/954

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1401109

**Now (15th May 2018) I've posted it here too:**

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1272

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a clean solution, but a workaround: I changed `driver.quit()` to `driver.close()`.
This is usually used to close a window. But if it's the last window it works. Tested with

- geckodriver 0.18.0
- Java 1.8.0_65
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (Jessie)
- Selenium 3.14.0
- Firefox 52.9.0